# Why can't I pass a connection variable to my function?

Tags: php, mysql, database, function

I can't seem to figure out why my function is not seeing $conn variable. Other functions seem to work just fine.

Here is a file in which I am calling my function:

```
require_once('../functions.php');
if('POST' == htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) {     
    $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
    $day = $_POST["day"];
    $month = $_POST["month"];
    $year = $_POST["year"];
    $type = '';
    $content = $_POST["content"];
    add_bullet($user_id, $day, $month, $year, $type, $content, $conn);   
}
```

And here is my functions.php

```
require_once('../include/db_connect.php');    
// other functions here..   
function add_bullet($user_id, $day, $month, $year, $type, $content, $conn) {    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `mbt`.`bullets` (`id`, `user`, `day`, `month`, `year`, `type`, `content`) VALUES ('', '$user_id', '$day', '$month', '$year', '$type', '$content');";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);      
}
```

My other functions seem to work just fine using same method.

Here is my db_connect.php

```
$dbserver = "xxx"; 
$dbuser = "xxx"; 
$dbpassword = "xxx"; 
$dbname = "xxx"; 

$conn = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname); 

if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); }
```

Comment: Did you start the session?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Yes, if I echo $user_id, it shows up.

Comment: Can you echo `$user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];` in your function and see whether it will work or not.

Comment: What does your errors says.. Can't find `function add_bullet()` >

Comment: where is your db_connect.php file?

Comment: Errors:
Notice: Undefined variable: conn in /blah-blah/include/userPage_owner.php on line 121

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /blah-blah/functions.php on line 116

Comment: try adding
global $conn; before calling your function .. it will be good to make method in db functions which will return your connection object..

Comment: So at some point the `$conn` variable is not set or is out of scope. Can you show your db_connect.php code (changing your real credentials)? (is it in a function...?)

Comment: Yes, SESSION echo's within function when you call it.

Comment: Show us what is inside `db_connect.php` while replacing credentials with `xxx`. Make sure you're not using `mysql_` functions or PDO to connect with also.

Comment: Please put that ^ in your question and not in comments. Then delete it from comments.

Comment: db_connect.php is located in include folder which is in the root folder.
functions.php is located in the root folder.

Comment: Try and put your `$conn` first `add_bullet($conn, $user_id, $day, $month, $year, $type, $content)` in both.

Comment: Also `include` instead of `require_once`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just use what ever variable you want from other files..
Add this global and try then..

```
$content = $_POST["content"];
global $conn;
add_bullet($user_id, $day, $month, $year, $type, $content, $conn);
```

A better idea is to define function inside your db file which will return the connection, this way you wont need to pass it but just to use the method..

Comment: This worked, thank you.

But from my understanding "global" isn't a safe way to do this. Is that true?

Comment: @Roman correct. You're relying on something outside of the scope that the variable; **a)** is named the same & exists. **b)** is the same data type as you expect it to be. An alternative would be to inject the variable

Comment: @Roman Like I said better use method to get connection. 
This is just a fast solution for your question.